# Is it possible to use Web API model validation on query parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, model-validation

I am currently trying to write a Web API application where one of the parameters I'd like to validate is a query parameter (that is, I wish to pass it in in the form `/route?offset=0&limit=100`):

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetItems(
    int offset = 0,
    int limit = 100)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Handle error
    }

    // Handle request
}
```

In particular, I want to ensure that "offset" is greater than 0, since a negative number will cause the database to throw an exception.

I went straight for the logical approach of attaching a `ValidationAttribute` to it:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetItems(
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)] int offset = 0,
    int limit = 100)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Handle error
    }

    // Handle request
}
```

This does not cause any errors at all.

After a lot of painful debugging into ASP.NET, it appears to me that this may be simply impossible. In particular, because the `offset` parameter is a method parameter rather than a field, the `ModelMetadata` is created using `GetMetadataForType` rather than `GetMetadataForProperty`, which means that the `PropertyName` will be `null`. In turn, this means that `AssociatedValidatorProvider` calls `GetValidatorsForType`, which uses an empty list of attributes even though the parameter had attributes on it.

I don't even see a way to write a custom `ModelValidatorProvider` in such a way as to get at that information, because the information that this was a function parameter seems to have been lost long ago. One way to do that might be to derive from the `ModelMetadata` class and use a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` as well but there's basically no documentation for any of this code so it would be a crapshoot that it actually works correctly, and I'd have to duplicate all of the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` logic.

Can someone prove me wrong? Can someone show me how to get validation to work on a parameter, similar to how the `BindAttribute` works in MVC? Or is there an alternative way to bind query parameters that will allow the validation to work correctly?

Comment: You would need a model with properties `int offset` and `int limit` and add the validation attributes to the model property. Then change the method parameter to be your model - `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetItems(yourModel model)`

Comment: I can't get that to bind the query parameteres `?offset=10&limit=10`. If you have a way, please answer the question.

Comment: It will bind fine - `offset` and `limit` need to be properties (with `{get; set; }`) and if you want defaults, then use a parameterless constructor

Comment: @coppro I'm sure you've already solved this, but in order to get query string parameters to bind to properties of a complex type, that complex type parameter must be annotated with `[FromUri]`.  For more information, see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a <del>*view*</del> request model class with those 2 properties and apply your validation attributes on the properties.

```
public class Req
{
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Enter number greater than 1 ")]
    public int Offset { set; get; }

    public int Limit { set; get; }
}
```

And in your method, use this as the parameter

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Req model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // to do  :return something. May be the validation errors?
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var modelStateVal in ModelState.Values.Select(d => d.Errors))
        {
            errors.AddRange(modelStateVal.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "Error", 
                                                                       Errors = errors });
    }
    // Model validation passed. Use model.Offset and Model.Limit as needed
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

When a request comes, the default model binder will map the request params(`limit` and `offset`, assuming they are part of the request) to an object of `Req` class and you will be able to call `ModelState.IsValid` method.

Comment: For anyone wondering exactly how the "default model binder will map the request params", the complex type parameter must be annotated with `[FromUri]`.  For more information, see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: In .net7, the endpoint method doesn't even get called when a validation error happens. I think in this case a custom validation attribute has to be written if someone would like to handle error or error messages.

Answer (score 6):

For **.Net 5.0** and validating **query parameters**:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace XXApi.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace XXApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult login([FromQuery] LoginModel model)
        {
             //.Net automatically validates model from the URL string
             //and gets here after validation succeeded
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Offset < 1)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Enter number greater than 1");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
```

Comment: In question it was asked to paas the model in Get but in answer its Post. Is it possible to do similar thing in GET?